# Is there a way to compare 2 columns of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Can somebody give me an idea to solve this? Finding 2 columns in a table has same data, we don't have idea about the columns to be same.

Can I move partial data into excel to check?

I have columns of about 39 and rows of 2B

[image]

- Col1 equal to col3
- col2 equal to col6
- col4 not equal col5

Output should show only columns that are common or some output which are common

Null Values are bothering me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean where 2 rows contain the same data? Otherwise aren't you just talking about `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1 = Column2`? Or do you mean the entire column containing the same data?

Comment: Are all columns of the same type?

Comment: please show sample data and expected results

Comment: edited ,posted the input and output

Comment: This is incredibly vague. I think you want to compare every single column of a row to every other column in that row. That is in itself a nasty undertaking as it demonstrates a departure from the basics of relational data. But even worse it you have not shown what you expect as output. And what about datatypes? Is every column the same datatype? You need to provide a LOT more detail here before you get a real answer. Try starting here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Personally, I'm totally ok with NULL values. What's your beef with them?

Comment: So... if I'm understanding this correctly you have 2 Billion rows. You only want the database to tell you when EVERY single record shares the same data between two columns. All 2 billion of them? Is your data really that terrible. Are you really that unfamiliar with it that you wouldn't have some idea of which ones are most likely repeated columns that you couldn't just write `SELECT count(*) FROM yourtable WHERE col1 = col2` and see if the count matches the entire table? Have you attempted any code here at all? What's your end game. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 39 columns and want to evaluate each against every other that gives you 741 column pairings to evaluate. This is possible to do in a concise manner **but I wouldn't recommend this for 2 billion rows!**

```
SELECT V1.name,
       V2.name
FROM   YourTable T WITH (TABLOCKX)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT (SELECT T.*
                            FOR xml path('row'), elements, type)) CA(X)
       CROSS APPLY CA.X.nodes('/row/*') N1(n)
       CROSS APPLY CA.X.nodes('/row/*') N2(n)
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(n1.n.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'), n1.n.value('.', 'nvarchar(4000)') )) V1(name, val)
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(n2.n.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'), n2.n.value('.', 'nvarchar(4000)') )) V2(name, val)
WHERE  V2.name < V1.name
       AND V1.val = V2.val
GROUP  BY V1.name,
          V2.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM   YourTable)
```

You should first profile the values in your columns. Get the `MIN`, `MAX` and `COUNT` of all columns (and potentially other aggregate data too for numeric columns). Discard any columns where `COUNT` is not equal to the whole row count as these won't match anything with your desired treatment of `NULLs` and identify sets of columns with the same `MIN` and `MAX` for further investigation.

If you do that with your example data you will see that the only pairs worth investigating are `Col1 <-> col3` and `Col2 <-> col6`. So you can then do a much more focused query to determine whether this is actually the case.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = col3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_rows_same_1_3, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = col6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_rows_same_2_6
FROM YourTable T
```